# What are the possible exceptions when using PropertiesService?

Tags: google-apps-script, exception

I had been reading the PropertiesService documentation of Google AppScript. And I had been using the following code for my addon :

`var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();`

I would just like to ask if this piece of code needs some exception handling. What is the best way of handling exceptions when using the PropertiesService?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. Related [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27002846/1595451), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43883266/1595451)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Rubén. I will keep that in mind. Your first related item, is a bit of an answer to my question. I think we will fall under the 500k quota. But it looks possible that a PropertiesService-Exception might happen during the execution of an addon. Aside from quota-related issues, have you seen any documentation related to PropertiesService-related exceptions? Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details to it (i.e. how the properties service is used, how many read/writes per execution / day, number of properties, maximum property size total properties size...) including a brief description of your search efforts.

Answer (score 2):

### Sample exception handling:

```js
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var myProperty = userProperties.getProperty('myNumber');
if(myProperty){
  myProperty = JSON.parse(myProperty) + 1;
}
else{
 myProperty = 1;
}
userProperties.setProperty('myNumber', JSON.stringify(myProperty))
```

- This code block increases a number stored in the user property `myNumber` by 1.
- First time, when the property `myNumber`  does not exist yet - it creates it by setting it to 1 and storing it with [`setProperty()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setpropertykey,-value)
- If the property already exists-  the `if` statement is entered and the property (always stored as a string) can be parsed and handled as a number

UPDATE

For completeness sake including the information from the comments.

You can handle exceptions with script properties in the following way:

```js
try{
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var myProperty = userProperties.getProperty('myNumber');
  if(myProperty){
    myProperty = JSON.parse(myProperty) + 1;
  }
  else{
   myProperty = 1;
  }
  userProperties.setProperty('myNumber', JSON.stringify(myProperty));
}
catch(error){
  console.log(error.stack);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I am sorry for the unclear question. But just like your code, my code does not envelope the call for 'PropertiesService.getUserProperties()' with a 'try-catch'. The code assumes that it will never generate an exception. Is it safe to proceed without a try-catch? Thanks.

Comment: Whenever possible, if you do not need to throw an error an `if... else` is better practice than a `try... catch`. In this specific case: if a property does not exist  - it will be undefined , the `if` condition will evaluate to  `false` and thus the `else` condition will be fullfilled. Absolutely no need for `try...catch`.

Comment: @zigannotschka thanks. What happens if you hit the 50k daily quota for PropertiesService though? Won't it generate an exception? But just that the result is undefined? Thank you again.

Comment: Ok, you are expecting to hit this quota, then you might use a `try...catch` indeed :-) This would be as simple as pasting the whole code block in my answer into the `try` block.